# Performance with materialized (indexed) view

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Consider this materialized view:

```
CREATE VIEW [vwPlaySequence] WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT 
    p.SiteIDNumber,
    dbo.ToUnsignedInt(p.SequenceNumber) AS PlayID, 
    p.SequenceNumber
FROM dbo.Play p
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX 
    PK_vwPlaySequence ON [vwPlaySequence] 
        (
            [PlayID], 
            [SiteIDNumber],
            [SequenceNumber]
        )
GO
```

The base table has a clustered index on SequenceNumber.

The following query on the base table executes on 160 million rows in 4 seconds:

```
select SiteIDNumber, min(SequenceNumber), max(SequenceNumber) from Play
group by SiteIDNumber
```

Here is the execution plan:

[image: Base execution plan]

And this is the same query on the view executes in 46 seconds:

```
select SiteIDNumber, min(SequenceNumber), max(SequenceNumber) from vwPlaySequence
group by SiteIDNumber
```

Its execution plan:

[image: View execution plan]

I'm not seeing what it is in these execution plans that would warrant such a drastic difference in run time. I've run both of these queries many times with the same results.

Comment: Both queries use the view. You have Enterprise Edition, correct? How many CPUs does the box have? Are you sure that the CI is not on SiteIDNumber? Because you're getting a stream aggregate on that. It must be sorted on that column.

Comment: Anyway you look at it, both queries are still on the same view but differ in execution time by an order of magnitude. The CI is the same for both.

Comment: One is parallel one is not. There's a reason I ask these questions... Does parallelism explain a 11x difference?

Comment: The box is a dual quad, 8 CPUs. The CI definition is above. I have tried to move the PlayID and SiteID around, but the results were the same.

Comment: Let's make an experiment: add OPTION (MAXDOP 1) to both queries. Are the times and plans the same now?

Comment: With MAXDOP 1, the table query runs in 45 sec and view in 46. You've nailed it. But why would the view query not be parallel?

Comment: Is any [`NonParallelPlanReason`](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/joe/sql-server-2012-execution-plans-nonparallelplanreason/) given? Wonder if it is related to the fact that [`Any reference to a table with a computed column that uses such a function will result in a serial plan`](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/12/23/forcing-a-parallel-query-execution-plan.aspx) and your view does in fact contain such a column.

Comment: The box is actually a dual six core. 12 processors, 11x difference, pretty much on-the-nose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both queries use the view. One is parallel one is not. You say that adding `OPTION (MAXDOP 1)` to both queries makes all differences disappear. This means that parallelism accounts for all of the differences.

There's no logical reason SQL Server has to pick a serial plan in one of the cases here. It is probably a bug or known limitation. I have encountered many limitations and strange behaviors with indexed view matching. In that sense I'm only mildly surprised.

Now that the difference is (kind of) explained, what to do about it?

1. You can try to force parallelism: `OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 8649) --set parallelism cost to zero`. This is an undocumented trace flag that is considered safe for production by some leading experts. I also do consider it to be safe.
2. You can try to select from the view using `WITH (NOEXPAND)`. This bypasses view matching and hopefully allows SQL Server to find a parallel plan.

Prefer option (2).

Comment: Option 2, NOEXPAND did it. The view query is taking about 5 seconds. I just wish I could hit the upvote more than once!